# Cant fine NMON on CentOS9 (EPEL installed)

Tags: linux, centos

I have EPEL installed on CentOS9

```
$> sudo dnf repolist
repo id                                           repo name
appstream                                         CentOS Stream 9 - AppStream
baseos                                            CentOS Stream 9 - BaseOS
epel                                              Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 9 - x86_64
epel-next                                         Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 9 - Next - x86_64
extras-common                                     CentOS Stream 9 - Extras packages
```

but `nmon` is not found:

```
$> sudo dnf -y install nmon
Last metadata expiration check: 0:01:46 ago on Wed 20 Apr 2022 14:49:52 CEST.
No match for argument: nmon
Error: Unable to find a match: nmon
```

*(I am sure it worked from CentOS8 few months ago)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system is behaving correct. For EPEL9 (CentOS9), there is no nmon package available. It is available for EPEL on CentOS 8.

Source:

- CentOS9: https://epel.mirror.liteserver.nl/9/Everything/x86_64/Packages/n/
- CentOS8: https://epel.mirror.liteserver.nl/8/Everything/x86_64/Packages/n/

If you would like it to be added, there is a procedure available to request packages in the EPEL project: https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/epel/epel-package-request/

Comment: for future references - I filed a bug report on fedora org and it was fixed a week ago.